# What is the name of com.mysql's datasource implementation?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jar, importerror

I just installed the official mysql jdbc driver, and I cannot find the class name for the datasource implementation.
I saw in a site that it was com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource, but eclipse does not recognize it.  (trying to import it gives me an error)
I tried reading the documentation, but I only found the name for the Driver.
I know there is another thread asking the same question, but it does not answer my question.
Please help me.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What you want exactly?you need jar for my-sql or need to configure database?jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDbName
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL Connector/J 8.0 the import is

```
import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource;
```